# Is there a conflict between memoir and sidenotes?

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, sidenotes

I am attempting to use the `memoir` package in conjuction with the `sidenotes` package, but when I attempt to compile, I get the following error:

`Option clash for package changepage`

and compilation  terminates.  It seems that compilation terminates at `\newcounter{sidenote}`  Is there something simple I'm missing that is causing this apparent conflict?

When I switch to `article` or `book`, I have no issues.

Comment: Well I think the problem is that `memoir`also provide the 
corresponding mechanism at the `sidenotes`package, so it is not necessary to load in the preamble if you use `memoir` class.

Comment: Memoir has integrated changepage. Also has (some) capability of sidenotes. Why you not stick just with memoir?

Comment: @Zarko I was not aware of that functionality in memoir; I'll check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The memoir class defines its own sidenotes called side footnotes:

```
\sidefootnote[〈num〉]{〈text〉}

\sidefootnotemark[〈num〉]

\sidefootnotetext[〈num〉]{〈text〉}
```

See section 12.5 in the memoir class documentation.

Do note that side footnotes of the memoir class are collected at the bottom of the margin, not next to the text that specified the note.